# Security error of Shiny App using Chrome

Tags: r, google-chrome, shiny

When one of my user tried to access our Shiny App using Chrome (31.0.1650.63 m). She got this error and a gray page:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://my-server/frost/**sockjs**/612/z8f64ie5/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established. (index):1

Uncaught SecurityError: Access to 'localStorage' is denied for this document (from comdata.html)

This Shiny App is working for other computers.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Is it possible to have the source of the shiny app? Does it have an iframe accessing local content?

Comment: I am sorry the source codes are not available. This app is distributed in our internal network. I am not sure about access local content, but didn't use any iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry. That bug was my fault and occurs anywhere Local Storage is either unavailable or disabled. It's fixed in Shiny Server Pro 1.1.0 which was released a few weeks ago.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just updated to shiny-server-1.1.0.10000-amd64.deb and started my chrome with disabled local storage (chrome.exe --disable-local-storage). However I still got the same error.

Comment: Sorry it is working now after I clean my browser cache.